# Mathematical sets of time periods?

Tags: java, time, intervals

I'm looking for a way to represent in Java a set of separated time periods that will support [mathematical sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) operations (union, intersection, etc).

Note that I'm expecting that sets that are the results of such operations will be merged into continuous time periods (as much as possible).

**Example:**

Say I have two of those hypothetical sets:

```
// imaginary constructor. numbers are unix times
TimeSet a = [(0,2), (3,6)]; 
TimeSet b = [(1,4), (5,7)];
```

Now lets perform some operations on them:

```
a.union(b);     // result = [(0,7)]
a.minus(b);     // result = [(0,1), (4,5)]
b.minus(a);     // result = [(2,3), (6,7)]
a.intersect(b); // result = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
a.diff(b);      // result = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]
```

Comment: Why would a union of `[(0,2), (3,6)]` and `[(1,4), (5,7)]` result in `[(0,7)]` rather than `[(0,2), (3,6),(1,4), (5,7)]`?

Comment: Because I also expect the result (of any operation) to be merged into continuous time periods (as possible as can).

Comment: @errr You should probably add that to the question, because that's a pretty different thing than a set.

Comment: Good question. Actually there is no java library which offers these features, also not JodaTime or JSR-310. And I don't expect these libraries to implement this anytime in the future. Anyway, for my library [Time4J](http://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) I will definitely implement it in a later release still this year.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. I ended up implementing it myself (not worrying too much about performance nor about thread-safety).

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found is JodaTime's capabilities.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html

The interval allows for methods like "abuts", "gap", and "overlap", which may then require additional conditional arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, but it's really not enough. It only handles continuous time periods and only supports a very small amount of the operations I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of general support for such interval features in Java, I have decided to implement it with my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J):

```
Moment d0 = Moment.of(0, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d1 = Moment.of(1, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d2 = Moment.of(2, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d3 = Moment.of(3, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d4 = Moment.of(4, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d5 = Moment.of(5, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d6 = Moment.of(6, TimeScale.POSIX);
Moment d7 = Moment.of(7, TimeScale.POSIX);

MomentInterval i1 = MomentInterval.between(d0,  d2);
MomentInterval i2 = MomentInterval.between(d3,  d6);
IntervalCollection<Moment> a = IntervalCollection.onMomentAxis().plus(i1).plus(i2);

MomentInterval i3 = MomentInterval.between(d1,  d4);
MomentInterval i4 = MomentInterval.between(d5,  d7);
IntervalCollection<Moment> b = IntervalCollection.onMomentAxis().plus(i3).plus(i4);

System.out.println(a.plus(b));
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/1970-01-01T00:00:02Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:01Z/1970-01-01T00:00:04Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:03Z/1970-01-01T00:00:06Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:05Z/1970-01-01T00:00:07Z)}

System.out.println(a.union(b));
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/1970-01-01T00:00:07Z)}

System.out.println(a.minus(b));
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/1970-01-01T00:00:01Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:04Z/1970-01-01T00:00:05Z)}

System.out.println(b.minus(a));
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:02Z/1970-01-01T00:00:03Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:06Z/1970-01-01T00:00:07Z)}

System.out.println(a.intersect(b)); 
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:01Z/1970-01-01T00:00:02Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:03Z/1970-01-01T00:00:04Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:05Z/1970-01-01T00:00:06Z)}

System.out.println(a.xor(b)); // your diff operator
// {[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/1970-01-01T00:00:01Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:02Z/1970-01-01T00:00:03Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:04Z/1970-01-01T00:00:05Z),[1970-01-01T00:00:06Z/1970-01-01T00:00:07Z)}
```